# GNOME Software/PackageKit lists only installed packages

Tags: fedora, gnome, packagekit

I noticed that GNOME Software on my Fedora 24 installation only shows packages that are already installed (even in the *featured* and *editor's picks* sections). I also can't search for new packages to install. Here's a screenshot of the *Graphics* category. On the left side, it shows only installed packages. On the right side (from another computer), it shows the correct list:

[image]

I found out that GNOME Software is a frontend for PackageKit, so I tried to use the CLI (`pkcon`). However, it also doesn't find most of the programs. For example, I wanted to search for *Shotwell* using the CLI. This is the output:

```
[user ~]$ pkcon search name shotwell
Searching by name             [=========================]
Finished                      [=========================]
[user ~]$
```

On the other computer, `pkcon` finds the package:

```
[user ~]$ pkcon search name shotwell
Searching by name             [=========================]
Starting                      [=========================]
Finished                      [=========================]
Available    shotwell-0.23.5-1.fc24.i686 (updates)    A photo organizer for the GNOME desktop
Available    shotwell-0.23.5-1.fc24.x86_64 (updates)    A photo organizer for the GNOME desktop
Available    shotwell-0.23.1-1.fc24.x86_64 (fedora)    A photo organizer for the GNOME desktop
[user ~]$
```

**How can I fix PackageKit to find all packages again?**

---

**Edit:** Output of `dnf repolist`:

```
repo id                    repo name                                      status
Dropbox                    Dropbox Repository                                  4
*fedora                    Fedora 24 - x86_64                             49.722
google-chrome              google-chrome                                       3
rpmfusion-free             RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Free                   352
rpmfusion-free-updates     RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Free - Updates         277
rpmfusion-nonfree          RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Nonfree                 89
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates  RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Nonfree - Updates      127
*updates                   Fedora 24 - x86_64 - Updates                    9.817
```

Comment: Do you have valid package sources in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`?

Comment: The package sources look okay to me (I added the output of `dnf repolist` to the question). Searching and installing packages, e.g., Shotwell, also still works with DNF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably was a caching problem. Although a reboot didn't help, killing the `packagekitd` process and restarting it manually fixed the problem:

```
sudo killall packagekitd
sudo /usr/libexec/packagekitd --verbose
```

(https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-bugs.html)

Executing `pkcon search name shotwell` after restarting `packagekitd` triggered a re-download of metadata. Searching with the CLI and GNOME Software works again.